# Openvpn TLS handshake failed: The server has no TLS ciphersuites in common with the client

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to connect to my OpenVPN server(openvpn 2.4.12,openssl 1.1.1k) with a centos 7 computer(openvpn 2.4.12， openssl 1.0.2k-fips)

Client error message

```
Sat May 28 21:06:05 2022 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx:1194, sid=48805bde ae6157ae
Sat May 28 21:07:05 2022 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds 
(check your network connectivity)
Sat May 28 21:07:05 2022 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Server log

```
xxx:1150 TLS error: The server has no TLS ciphersuites in common with the client. 
Your --tls-cipher setting might be too restrictive.
xxx:1150 OpenSSL: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no 
shared cipher
xxx:1150 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
xxx:1150 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
xxx:1150 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
xxx:1150 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

pls help

Comment: Did you actually read the error messages you posted ? The instruction *`Your --tls-cipher setting might be too restrictive.`* seems pretty straightforward. So to state the obvious: start by investigating that setting

Comment: Of course, I have noticed this. But I'm having trouble with this setting though. Been doing a lot of google searches.